# manera de hacer esto en sql server

Tags: sql

Tengo dos tablas

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[eventos publico](
[ep0] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ep1] [int] NOT NULL,
[nombre] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[finicio] [date] NOT NULL,
[ffin] [date] NOT NULL,
[importe] [money] NOT NULL,
[envigor] [bit] NOT NULL,
[descripcion] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
```

y

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[solicitudes invitaciones](
[si0] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[si1] [int] NOT NULL,
[si2] [int] NOT NULL,
[fecha] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[referencia] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
[nombre] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[apellidos] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[region] [int] NOT NULL,
[correo] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
[estado] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[fbaja] [date] NULL,
```

Las dos están relacionadas: ep0=si1

Quisiera que al intentar dar de baja eventos publico pregunte antes si hay una clave si1 correspondiente a ese eventos publico. Si es así, que no dé de baja eventos publico y en su lugar que ponga 0 a envigor, Si no es así, que lo dé de baja.

Lo que quiero hacer es no dar de baja un evento (eventos publico) si hay una solicitud de invitación (solicitudes invitaciones) de ese evento. En su lugar que lo ponga como obsoleto (envigor=0). Todo para no perder la solicitud de invitación.

¿se puede hace? ¿Cómo?

Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso yo veo conveniente crear un *trigger AFTER DELETE* en la tabla eventos_publico (evita usar espacios en la tabla) donde en el trigger reciba el valor de la tabla ep0 y te creas una variable @cont de tipo integer que agarre el valor de la consulta:
`select @cont = count (*) from solicitudes_invitaciones where si1 = ep0`
y luego te haces un *if @cont > 0* haces el update de tu tabla eventos_publico y como camino del *else* realizas el borrado de los registros.